# Drawing an SVG File in WinRT

Tags: c#, image, webview, svg, windows-runtime

I'm trying to draw a SVG File. So far I've tried using an Image tag and a WebView with the svg itself or an object / embed tag. Nothing so far seems to help, and all the dll's I've found so far need .NET.

Examples of what I've tried so far (note: Paths have all been tried with or without ms-appx:///, note2: using img tag in webview for non-svg types hasn't worked either)

WebView:

```
webView.NavigateToString("<embed src='circle1.svg' type='image/svg+xml' />");
webView.NavigateToString("<object data='circle1.svg' type='image/svg+xml' />");
webView.NavigateToString("<svg>....</svg>");
```

Image:

```
<Image Source='circle1.svg'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can include external images this way, have you tried with other image formats? Have you tried using an absolute path? I would also consider using the [data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) tag as image source instead of an external file.

Example (from wikipedia):

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" 
alt="Red dot">
```

Additionally, there is project in codeplex called [xamltune](http://xamltune.codeplex.com) that can convert a svg file into an xaml file. Maybe you can insert the output xaml code in your application instead of using a WebView.

Comment: Good ideas, and luckily we could change the image format. The converter wouldn't have worked because it was data obtained at runtime. Thanks for your help anyway.